# Different outputs using different Data Structure

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, hash, unordered-map

I am asking this question in relation to the following problem : https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/count-pairs-with-given-sum5022/1

Given an array of `N` integers, and an integer `K`, find the number of pairs of elements in the array whose sum is equal to `K`.

Count pairs with given sum in `O(n)` time and `O(n)` space.
Given `n = 4`, `k = 6`, `arr = [1 5 7 1]`

This is part of my code:

```
#define MOD 1000007
int getPairsCount(int arr[], int n, int k) {
    // long long int h[MOD] = {0}; // This is the one I used originally
    // but it given 3 as the answer for the input n = 4, k = 6, arr = [1 5 7 1],
    
    unordered_map<long long, long long> h; // But when using map, it gives correct output as 2

    long long int count = 0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        h[arr[i]]+=1;
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        count+=h[k - arr[i]];
        
        if(k == 2*arr[i])count--;
    }
    
    return (count/2);
    }
};
```

Anyone please explain why there is a difference.
MOD was chosen based on the max number `arr[i]` can have `(arr[i]<=10^6)`.
even using `memset` to set all values to 0 didn't work.

Then why there is a difference in using a `map` and `array` as hash?

Comment: What do you hope to learn from these contest/challenge/competitive coding/hacking sites? If it's to learn C++, you won't learn anything there. Like in this case, the correct solution is based on a mathematical or a programming trick. If you don't know what the trick is and attempt to code a brute-force approach, the program either runs slow, or fails to handle an obscure edge case. If you're trying to learn C++, you won't learn anything from meaningless online contest sites [but only from a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @sam https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IM-hdoevo5M&ab_channel=TheTEACHERSOCIOLOGY

Comment: Well, @πάνταῥεῖ -- a nifty analogy. Except that the airplanes did actually bring some stuff that was useful to the natives.

Comment: @Sam Yup, that's what got lost [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Answer (score 0):

Basic debugging: verify that data is what you think it is. This is easier to do with a debugger, but streaming diagnostics also works. Let's look at the evaluation of `count+=h[k - arr[i]]` over several iterations (using the input from the question).

```
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        std::cerr << "count += h[k - arr[i]]\t" // To remind us what we are looking at
                     "count += h[" << k << " - " << arr[i] << "]\t"
                     "count += h[" << k - arr[i] << "]\t"
                     << count << " += " << h[k - arr[i]] << "\n";
        count+=h[k - arr[i]];
        
        if(k == 2*arr[i])count--;
    }
```

Possible output (using the array instead of the unordered map):

```
count += h[k - arr[i]]  count += h[6 - 1]   count += h[5]   0 += 1
count += h[k - arr[i]]  count += h[6 - 5]   count += h[1]   1 += 2
count += h[k - arr[i]]  count += h[6 - 7]   count += h[-1]  3 += 140720947826640
count += h[k - arr[i]]  count += h[6 - 1]   count += h[5]   140720947826643 += 1
```

At this point, the problem should be obvious (at the very least, the iteration where the problem occurs should be obvious). Even though every `long long` value is a valid key for an `unordered_map` from `long long` to something, at least half of those values are invalid indices for an array.

Comment: Oh, I may have forgot to use abs(k-arr[i]). Thank you for the answer.